# in chart js tooltip font size is not working

Tags: charts, chart.js

I want to make big font of tooltip in chart js, but unfortunately it is not working for me, here i have added my code, can anyone please check my code, and help me to resolve this issue ?

```js
options: {
  plugins: {
    legend: {
      display: true,
      position: 'bottom',
      labels: {
        font: {
          size: 30
        }
      }
    },
    tooltips: {
      font: {
        size: 30
      }
    }
  },

}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can define different fonts for the title, body and footer of the tooltip so you will need to define it in those specific places:

```js
var options = {
  type: 'line',
  data: {
    labels: ["Red", "Blue", "Yellow", "Green", "Purple", "Orange"],
    datasets: [{
        label: '# of Votes',
        data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3],
        borderColor: 'pink'
      }
    ]
  },
  options: {
    plugins: {
      tooltip: {
        titleFont: {
          size: 100
        },
        bodyFont: {
          size: 50
        },
        footerFont: {
          size: 20 // there is no footer by default
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

var ctx = document.getElementById('chartJSContainer').getContext('2d');
new Chart(ctx, options);
```

```html
<body>
  <canvas id="chartJSContainer" width="600" height="400"></canvas>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/3.5.1/chart.js"></script>
</body>
```